# Strange code breaks build in MSVC. What does it mean?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, compiler-errors, rapidxml

I am trying to include rapidxml into my current project. However, it would not build.

Visual Studio would complain about this piece of code (rapidxml.hpp:419+451):

```
419: void *memory = allocate_aligned(sizeof(xml_attribute<Ch>));
420: xml_attribute<Ch> *attribute = new(memory) xml_attribute<Ch>;
```

The compiler would say

> rapidxml.hpp(420): error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memory'

And I kind of see how this would confuse the compiler. It actually confuses me quite a bit, too. What is the `(memory)` part of `new(memory) xml_attribute<Ch>` doing there?

If I delete that `(memory)` part, it compiles just fine.
Also, gcc compiles it just fine with `(memory)` included.

**Edit:**
Oh, and I overloaded `new` with `DEBUG_NEW` to do some memory debugging. `DEBUG_NEW` does not support placement new.

Comment: It should always be easier to confuse an user than the compiler... The compiler should know its language and all gory details, while we users are limited and can only know so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "placement new".  It instantiates an instance of xml_attribute in `memory` instead of allocating new memory for it.  See:

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10

I'm not sure why VC2010 has a problem with the syntax though.

Answer (score 3):

This is my suggestion. The "memory" itself is defined somewhere also as a macro, and is getting expanded which causes the problem. So search for `#define.memory` (using regular expressions) to see if memory is defined as a macro.

As for the next statement, this form:

```
new(allocator) ObjectType(...)
```

is used when you want to use your own memory allocator to allocate memory for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Worth noting that once you want some specific class objects to be allocated in custom way you should just overload its `operator new` member function instead of using placement-new.

Answer (score 3):

Have you got #include <new> in that file?

Comment: @David: I don't know about VC, but g++ requires it.

Comment: I do, there is `#include <new>` in that file.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax `new (pointer) type( argument )` is called *placement new*, and it basically represents a call to the `type` constructor with the given `argument` over the memory previously allocated in `pointer`.

The syntax, in as much as it is shown, is correct. Maybe a couple of lines above there is a missing semi-colon or syntax error that is confusing the parser, but `memory` as an identifier is correclty used defined in the previous line. (And it is not reserved by the language for the implementation)